# VerifyError occurs after applying android5.1.1 Proguard. Please tell me how to fix it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

this is proguard-rules.pro

```
-dontwarn android.net.wifi.**

-keep class android.net.wifi.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.net.wifi.** { *; }

-keep  public class com.uns.patientcheck.UpdateInfoActivity$JavaScriptMethods
-keepclassmembers  class com.uns.patientcheck.UpdateInfoActivity$JavaScriptMethods {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}

-dontwarn android.content.**
-keep class android.content.Context.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.content.Context.** { *; }

-dontwarn android.app.**
-keep class android.app.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.app.** { *; }
```

this is logcat

```
03-07 16:56:53.311 14354-14354/? E/art: Verification failed on class com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity in /data/app/com.uns.patientcheck-2/base.apk because: Verifier rejected class com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity due to bad method void com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity.onResume()
03-07 16:56:53.313 14354-14354/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.uns.patientcheck, PID: 14354
                                                   java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity due to bad method void com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity.onResume() (declaration of 'com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity' appears in /data/app/com.uns.patientcheck-2/base.apk)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1606)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I tried to solve this by applying it, but I could not solve it.

```
-keepclassmembers  class com.uns.patientcheck.LoginActivity {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
    }
```

I have to apply the pro guard. How can I solve this problem? I am a novice developer, please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this 
The problem was due to the instance referenced by onResume () of the login activity

```
-dontwarn android.content.**
-keep public class android.content.** { *; }
```

This solved it

It's a problem because I did not read my android studio warnings properly.